# Android Login Screen Constraint Layout

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am new to Android Studio and I am looking at a project an acquaintance did. See attached activity_login.xml shot.

[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtGfW.png)

See also XML behind. Question is. What is this line(red arrow) and Why can't I add items to the bottom of the line and why can't I increase the Constraint Layout height any further? I'm new to this and this has me stumpt. Please help or show me where to look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".views.activity.LoginActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--  <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>-->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_margin_90"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_splash"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_margin_50"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_custom_bg"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_margin_10"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textColor="@color/tertiary_text_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/primary_hint_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_18"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

        <!--<EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_custom_bg"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_18"
            android:autoLink="all"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_margin_10"
            android:textColor="@color/tertiary_text_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/primary_hint_text_color"
            />
    -->


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_custom_bg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_10"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/show_pass_btn"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_margin_10"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:textColor="@color/tertiary_text_color"
                android:textColorHint="@color/primary_hint_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_18"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/show_pass_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_margin_40"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_margin_40"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_5"
                android:onClick="ShowHidePass"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_margin_5"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_eye_disable" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_margin_50"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_margin_40"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_50"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_16"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rl_pass"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgot_pass"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_margin_50"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_50"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_20"
            android:text="@string/action_forgot_pass"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/tertiary_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_16"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rl_pass"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rl_pass"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: connect the outermost constraint to the bottom and set the height to 0dp.